# E/FirebaseInstanceId: Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED. Won't retry the operation

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to add FireBase cloud Messaging SDK to my app, and I step and step with the guide of FireBase
1, create an APP in FireBase Dashboard
2, download google-servers.json into Assest folder
3, Import FirebaseMessaging.unitypackage
4, Build app in android studio
5, run app in android simulator(mumu simulator) with AS-debug mode。
then I get the error：
I/firebase: Firebase Cloud Messaging API Initialized
I/Unity: Firebase Cloud Messaging API Initialized
error: E/FirebaseInstanceId: Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED. Won't retry the operation.
I/Unity: Firebase Messaging Initialized
I/Unity: RequestPermissionAsync completed
I read the issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1286  ,but it's not work

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1286
I find lot of ways to resolve it， but not work

Answer (score 0):

AUTHENTICATION_FAILED error message is usually caused by an environment issue. Make sure that you are using the latest Google Play Services version available, as well as the latest version of the Firebase SDK.

Also, if your connection has firewall, ensure that you open the ports 5228, 5229, and 5230 (although FCM typically only uses 5228) to properly access FCM. This information can also be seen [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ports_and_your_firewall).